# div className="filter-bubbles five-sixths column"

Tags: javascript

Hi I see a javascript file where a return statement is written like:

```
<div className={'filter-popup align-left- popover '+filterClass}>
                      <div className="tree tree-bb-piano_content_provider"><div className="tree-search popover-header shaded-">
                <div className="tree-search-container">
```

what can I understand from this?

Comment: that it is some template?

Comment: yes, it is a part of a javascript file dot JS

Comment: Any more details on this? Was it part of a system or framework? What else is written in the function with return that statement?

Answer (score 0):

This look like a react template. http://facebook.github.io/react/